# In mobile, can different apps respond to a browser call-to-action and open directly?

Tags: android, ios

I'd like to design a cross platform protocol that any app on mobile or app on your desktop can respond to.

On desktop the best example is torrents, where you have a magnet link of the form `magnet:?urn:btih:abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc` etc. that can be opened by any app that supports the `magnet:` scheme. There also exists `.torrent` files which can be opened by anything that supports `.torrents` (although this won't open directly).

Is something like this possible on mobile? From my initial research it appears that iOS doesn't let multiple apps register the same uri scheme so `customuniversalscheme://` won't work. I also vaguely recall mobile safari opening files in browser and not in separate apps or even being able to download the files, but i'm not sure about that anymore...

What about android? Can multiple apps respond to the same custom scheme? Files can be downloaded on android, but can files be opened directly in browser?

Is the user flow I am thinking about possible on mobile? If so, how? If not, what's the next best alternative?

Answer (score 0):

So I think your comparison with the desktop torrent flow is a bit wrong. On desktop you can choose the default app to open a file or you can "Open With" an app that you want, on mobile it's a little bit different and more complicated.

So mainly on mobile platforms you open an app with a deep-link and iOS has two ways of deep-links:

- the old and well known URL scheme that you defined above
- the universal-link, this one is used a lot (iOS 9 and above) to forward a link, that usually will be opened in browser, to the app that responds to the universal link (it's very similar to the URL scheme thinghy)

For Android you have something similar using `intent-filters` and as far as I know it's possible to have multiple apps that respond to the same deep-link, but if I remember correctly the user will be prompted with an app picker (to select which app to use).

Now this is a short summary about deep-links, but from my experience the main issue with deep-links is now how you create them, it's about the app that must "forward" them. For example, on Android there are so many web browsers (not chrome) that won't forward the deep-link to the system in order to check if there is an app that can open them.

Now, if you can pass this problem, what I think you could do to unify the implementation for both platforms is to link your framework/lib/app to an API that will generate a unique deep-link scheme for every app. For example I want to "respond" to your deep-links so I register my app on your platform, with the bundle id and package name (which are unique), and your system will generate a unique combo of package name / bunde id and other number. When your lib/app/framework launch you will fetch all the configured bundles and try to fire a deep-link for each of them, this approach is kind of limited by the number of registered apps.